# How to enable user select in a readOnly html element on iPad safari?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile-webkit

I have an HTML element in my web page on iPad and it must be read only to prevent users updating the content,using `readOnly='readOnly'` makes the element unselectable and text content of the element can not be copied at all.

is there any way to make the element read only and the user can select/copy the text content????

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. This question is very different than the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Agreed. This issue is specific to iPad text input fields and the readOnly attribute and the answer below from aomar is the only solution I've encountered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just i removed the `readOnly` attribute and added the following `onkeydown` and `oncut` events to simulate `readOnly` behavior

```
<input type="textarea" 
    onkeydown="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();return false;" 
    oncut="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();return false;">
```

Comment: Careful! This breaks the text field's keyboard shortcuts (e.g. CMD + C or CMD + A) in most browsers.

Comment: it's for iPad not for anything else

Comment: iPad users may use an external keyboard, which is very common on ipad Pro. Keyboard shortcuts will be broken for them as well.