# On Safari Mobile, auto-select all the text of a read-only input on focus

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to use an input text box as a URL sharing widget. Fairly standard: when you click on the textbox, all of the text inside is automatically highlighted to make it easy to copy and paste. It's set as `read-only='read-only'` to prevent the user from changing the URL accidentally, and the click event is set to `this.focus();this.select();`. This works on the desktop.

The problem arises with Safari Mobile (I'm using iOS 7.0.6). From what I can tell, the `read-only` prevents using the standard `setSelectionRange(0,9999);`. But if I turn off `read-only` and just use javascript to prevent editing, the iOS keyboard shows once the text input has focus.

**tl;dr** On Safari Mobile I'd like to have the uneditable textbox be entirely selected on focus but without showing the keyboard (ideally it would show the copy/paste menu too, but I think that's a stretch). Is this possible?

JSFiddle shamelessly forked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13761214/2708274):

[JSFiddle showing input with read-only set (Doesn't work on Safari Mobile iOS 7.0.6)](http://jsfiddle.net/kY6dH/5/)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766671/how-to-enable-user-select-in-a-readonly-html-element-on-ipad-safari. Long story short -- it appears mobile safari doesn't handle the readonly attribute very well. I've concluded it's necessary to remove the readonly attribute to allow for text to be copied. :-(